# Control AVPlayer buffering

Tags: ios, avplayer

I want to stop `AVPlayer` buffering when the phone is not connected to Wi-Fi. Additionally, I want to resume buffering when the phone connects back to Wi-Fi. 
Is it possible to control the `AVPlayer` buffering ?